# Trying to connect Google Analytics to Google Data Studio - error 400

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I have an issue with connecting GA to Data Studio. Everything seems to work fine but there's some kind of problem that I just don't know how to solve. Maybe somebody have already had something similar before.
Although my account is authorized and I can choose everything - Connectors, Account, Property and View and even see the fields - when I add it to report, I get Error 400.

```
400. That’s an error.
```

Error: admin_policy_enforced

Access to your account data is restricted by policies within your organization. Please contact administrator for more information.
Request Details

```
client_id=myid-myanotherid.apps.googleusercontent.com
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
access_type=offline
response_type=code token
immediate=false
pageId=none
user_id=myid@myemail.com
include_granted_scopes=true
proxy=oauth2relay2050978162
redirect_uri=postmessage
origin=https://datastudio.google.com
gsiwebsdk=1
state=781464001|0.792356641
jsh=m;/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.6hIrKdeK3RQ.O/m=__features__/am=AQ/rt=j/d=1/rs=AGLTcCNV6CBDIuxs3srAO9rORg8A8mF6Kg
hd=sotrender.com
That’s all we know.
```

It seems to bit a problem with Google Drive. But when I create a new report in Data Studio, it creates a file in my Drive so I don't really know why is that happening. GA works fell because I can see all the accounts, views, fields, etc. when creating a report. After I click 'Create a new data source', choose the data source and click 'Add to report' - the message above appears and I can't really do anything else.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Does your organization use G Suite? If so there's an administrator inside your company responsible for G Suite settings. He has restricted you or your whole organization of either using Analytics, using Data Studio or linking both together. You need to get in contact with your company admin to help you get the correct access to perform this change.